# No Checkbox in ShinyApp

Tags: r, shiny

I'm trying to display a csv file and create checkboxes to allow filtering. The app runs without any errors but I get a blank box where the checkboxes would be. How can I get the checkboxes to show up?

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

df <- read.csv("new_and_deactivated_accounts.csv", header = TRUE)

ui <- fluidPage(

    # Application title
    titlePanel("GIS Workload"),

    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
            conditionalPanel(
                'input.dataset === "df"',
                             checkboxGroupInput("checkbox", "Select something",
                                                names(df), selected = names(df))
            )
        ),

        mainPanel(
           tabsetPanel(
               id='df',
               tabPanel(DT::dataTableOutput("mytable1"))
        )
    )
)
)

server <- function(input, output) {

    output$mytable1 <- DT::renderDataTable({
        DT::datatable(df[, input$checkbox, drop = FALSE])
    })
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Here's a portion of what displays, where the checkboxes should be are empty and because it's a semi-private, I opted not to show the data, but included the headers.
[image]

Comment: Your conditionalPanel check for `input$dataset=="df"`. But there is no `input$dataset` in your app.

Comment: That got it, though I needed to remove the === "df" to get it to work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are there, just hidden as you are using a conditional panel and the condition isn't being met.

You can remove this part, or ensure the conditions are being met:

`conditionalPanel('input.dataset === "df"',`

Here is your full code with that line removed, and mtcars used instead of your data:

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

df <- mtcars

ui <- fluidPage(

    # Application title
    titlePanel("GIS Workload"),

    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
            checkboxGroupInput("checkbox", "Select something",
            names(df), selected = names(df))

        ),

        mainPanel(
           tabsetPanel(
               id='df',
               tabPanel(DT::dataTableOutput("mytable1"))
        )
    )
)
)

server <- function(input, output) {

    output$mytable1 <- DT::renderDataTable({
        DT::datatable(df[, input$checkbox, drop = FALSE])
    })
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is some generic Shiny code that should help you.

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

mymtcars <- mtcars
mymtcars[["Select"]] <- paste0('<input type="checkbox" name="row_selected" value=',1:nrow(mymtcars),' checked>')
mymtcars[["_id"]] <- paste0("row_", seq(nrow(mymtcars)))

callback <- c(
  sprintf("table.on('click', 'td:nth-child(%d)', function(){", 
          which(names(mymtcars) == "Select")),
  "  var checkbox = $(this).children()[0];",
  "  var $row = $(this).closest('tr');",
  "  if(checkbox.checked){",
  "    $row.removeClass('excluded');",
  "  }else{",
  "    $row.addClass('excluded');",
  "  }",
  "  var excludedRows = [];",
  "  table.$('tr').each(function(i, row){",
  "    if($(this).hasClass('excluded')){",
  "      excludedRows.push(parseInt($(row).attr('id').split('_')[1]));",
  "    }",
  "  });",
  "  Shiny.setInputValue('excludedRows', excludedRows);",
  "});"
)

ui = fluidPage(
  verbatimTextOutput("excludedRows"),
  DTOutput('myDT')
)

server = function(input, output) {

  output$myDT <- renderDT({

    datatable(
      mymtcars, selection = "multiple",
      options = list(pageLength = 5,
                     lengthChange = FALSE,
                     rowId = JS(sprintf("function(data){return data[%d];}", 
                                        ncol(mymtcars)-1)),
                     columnDefs = list( # hide the '_id' column
                       list(visible = FALSE, targets = ncol(mymtcars)-1)
                     )
      ),
      rownames = FALSE,
      escape = FALSE,
      callback = JS(callback)
    )
  }, server = FALSE)

  output$excludedRows <- renderPrint({
    input[["excludedRows"]]
  })
}

shinyApp(ui,server, options = list(launch.browser = TRUE))
```